# Retrieve full URL in Twitter Search API

Tags: twitter

I am using the Twitter Search API to search for a URL. Here's an example:
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=url.com

The JSON response gives me the shortened URL of each search result. Is there a way for me to retrieve the full URL of each result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to pragmatically request each URL yourself and see where it redirect to.

Answer (score 4):

From 11/2011, you can use the include_entities=true parameter to retrieve full tweet entities, which include the expanded URL (and a lot more)

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search

Answer (score 1):

On Twitter Search, you can use the same URL endpoint that Twitter Search uses to expand shortened URLs: http://search.twitter.com/hugeurl. For example, if you wanted to expand the shortened URL http://bit.ly/jIhqhq:

```
$ curl "http://search.twitter.com/hugeurl?url=http://bit.ly/jIhqhq"
http://edition.cnn.com/2011/SPORT/football/05/03/may.03.cnn.top.10/index.html/
```

This will only work for the more popular shorteners ([bit.ly](http://bit.ly), [j.mp](http://j.mp), etc.) Also, this AJAX endpoint is pretty aggressively rate-limited, so don't expect to be able to use this for a production application, but something like 10 times an hour should be fine.

Comment: It seems this hugeurl API had gone away.

Answer (score 0):

Not currently through Twitter. On Twitter.com, those shortened URLs are automatically expanded into something readable, however search.twitter.com doesn't seem to be expanding the t.co shortened URLs at this time.